# Saving Macro Enabled workbook as .xlxs

Tags: vba, excel

I've set up a worksheet with a Macro in that checks the formatting of various cells, and at the end saves it as a normal .xlxs spreadsheet in the users C: drive.

The code I've been trying is

```
Dim sheetName As String
Dim tempwb As Workbook
Dim currentworkbook As String
Dim currentformat As Long

    currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    currentformat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
    sheetname = "Risk Info"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Copy before:=tempwb.Sheets(1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).SaveAs Filename:="C:\xstreamv1\inbox\xstream_data_sheet.xlsx", FileFormat :=51
    tempwb.Close savechanges:=False

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=currentworkbook, FileFormat:=currentformat
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

When I run the Macro it does create the xlxs copy I want, but it also creates and opens copies of the sheet I'm working in, and then crashes for a while!

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with information how to duplicate the environment in which this is running. The code you provide can't run - `tempwb` for example is not instantiated, yet the code tries to close it. You also mix `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook`, but there's no indication what `activeWorkbook` is. And you send the `Close` command to it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the poor layout of the question. I've managed to fix it now, using advice from Cyboashu, and other forums I found. Fixed code is:

```
Sub DataCheck()
'
' To check that the data entered in XStream is correct
'

Dim sheetName As String
Dim startRow As Integer, startCol As Integer
Dim endRow As Long, endCol As Integer
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
Dim RC As Range
Dim c As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim a As Double
Dim tempwb As Workbook
Dim currentworkbook As String
Dim currentformat As Long

Set tempwb = Workbooks.Add

currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
cuurentformat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat


sheetName = "Risk Info" 'Your sheetname

    startRow = 3 'start row for the loop
    endRow = 20

    c = 0

    ...

    If c = 0 Then

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Copy before:=tempwb.Sheets(1)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).SaveAs Filename:="C:\xstreamv1\inbox\xstream_data_sheet.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
        tempwb.Close savechanges:=False

    Else
        MsgBox "There were issues with " & c & " entries. See red cells"
    End If





End Sub
```